# JMS Publish/Subscriber with Glass Fish - How to view data sent to MDB on a web page

Tags: java, ejb, jms, publish-subscribe

I have a web application form which collects data and sends to JMS topic. From the topic, I am able to retrieve using EJB through message driven bean. How can I show the retrieved data on a jsf page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message driven bean will not help you if you want to display the message on JSF. You will need to create a stateless session bean ( presuming you want to implement this action in a EJB) which reads the message from topic and returns back to the client.
I am not sure how JSF interaction would look like but in a standard JSP-Servlet based architecture it would be like -

*`MessageDisplay.jsp -> MessageDisplayHandlerservlet.java -> MessageRetrieverSessionBean.java ( Use JMS API to connect to the topic and read message)`*

Please note that you don't have to have the stateless bean to read the message, you can do that even from a Servlet or backing bean(If I get this term right in context of JSF) .

Comment: Thanks Amit. So I don't really need a MDB to get data from a topic? I'll try with servlets

Comment: Yeah MDBs are invoked whenever a message gets added to a subscribed topic or queue. In your case you do not want this behavior hence MDB is not needed. If you think this answers your question, could you please mark this as an answer.